# my dictionary doesn't work properly

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am using a dictionary object to sort and count values and print them to a sheet. Someone else helped me to write the code, so much of it seems like witchcraft to me.

In my data I have 30 blocks containing 18 trials each. I also have 1 practice block before the 30 blocks, and 10 transfer blocks after the 30 blocks. all the code was written using a data sample that did not include the transfer blocks, but I intend to copy/paste other data files into the original file that will contain transfer blocks.

Somehow, my code knows to ignore the practice block (which is what I want), but is also ignoring the transfer blocks when I copy/paste the data in (which is not what I want). I have no idea why the code is behaving like this.

Here is the code for the dictionary object:

```
Dim dBT As Object 'global dictionary

Sub buttonpresscount()

    'constants for column positions
    Const COL_BLOCK As Long = 1
    Const COL_TRIAL As Long = 2
    Const COL_ACT As Long = 7
    Const COL_AOI As Long = 8
    Const COL_RT As Long = 16

    Dim rng As Range, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Dim d, r As Long, k, resBT()

    Set sht = Worksheets("full test")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dBT = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = sht.Range("B7:T" & lastrow)

    d = rng.Value  'get the data into an array

    ReDim resBT(1 To UBound(d), 1 To 1) 'resize the array which will
                                        '  be placed in ColT

    'get unique combinations of Block and Trial and pressedcounts for each
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_ACT) <> "", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)         'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("T7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

    'clear dictionary
    dBT.RemoveAll

'count AOI entries
 For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If resBT(r, 1) = 1 Then    'only proceed with trials with 1 button press
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("U7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

Call createsummarytable
Call PopSummaryAOI(dBT)

dBT.RemoveAll

'retrieve and print reaction times to data summary sheet
   For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        If resBT(r, 1) <> "" Then
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = d(r, COL_RT)
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r

 'Populate array with last row reaction time for each trial
        For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

Call PopSummaryRT(dBT)

End Sub
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of some of my data:]

Here is a screenshot of the summary table:

[image]

How do I get the code to still ignore the practice block, but analyse the transfer blocks?

A secondary problem I'm having is that (if you look at my second screenshot, at trial 10 of block 29) some reaction time values are not being printed even though there is a value printed for AOIentries.

For those interested in looking at the sample data and source code as well as submacros, [here it is.](http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest_2)

**UPDATE:** I have been trying to find a pattern with regards to the missing reaction time values in the summary table - the missing RT values only appear in blocks where there are other missing AOIentries and RT values. That is to say, when a block has a blank AOIentries and RT pairing, there is always another RT value missing. In blocks with no blank AOIentries values, there are no missing RT values. So leaving an AOIentries cell blank in a particular block is causing more than one RT value to be left blank, but only in that block, and not every RT value in the block.

Additionally, the RT values that are missing that aren't supposed to be missing are always from the trial that appears immediately before the trial whose AOIentries value is excluded (trials presentations are randomised in each block). E.g. if trial 17 had 2 button presses, the AOIentries value and RT value for trial 17 would be left blank, but if trial 6 was the trial immediately preceding trial 17, it would also have a blank RT value.

Comment: With a Dictionary object, you `.Add(Key, Value)`. Your code is treating it like a regular array. See [MS ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: Without the source data and the other Sub's I doubt this will be easy to figure out...  It would help if you could share the workbook (via DropBox or similar)

Comment: Edited to include source data and submacros. And why would someone edit out my title pun???

Comment: @PatricK Could you elaborate on why this would cause the dict to overlook transfer blocks and practice block? There was a reason why I chose to use a dict object, rather than an array. I forget what it was.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't understand how the code distinguishes between practice block, block, and transfer block. The only code I can see has any relevance is `COL_BLOCK`

Comment: `lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` should be `lastrow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`  That's not the real issue though, but too late here for me so I'll maybe pick up again tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  'retrieve and print reaction times to data summary sheet
  For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        If resBT(r, 1) <> "" Then
            k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
            dBT(k) = d(r, COL_RT)
        Else
            dBT(k) = ""
        End If
   Next r
```

You will clear `dBT(k)` in some instances where previously it had a value for the AOI data (where you were testing for `resBT(r, 1) = 1` to decide if to blank that postion in the dictionary).  That's what's creating your "gaps" in the summary data.

As for your "Transfer" trials, in your data you have this labelling:

```
Block               Trial  
Transfer Block 2    Transfer trial, 3
```

on your summary sheet it's this:

```
Block               Trial  
Transfer Block 2    Trial, 3
```

so it doesn't match when you try to populate the summary

Make this change to `createsummarytable` and the data will populate:

```
'print trial number headings
 For j = 1 To 18
     .Cells((Startrow + 1) + (5 * i), j).Value = IIf(i < 31, _
                                     "Trial, " & j, _
                                     "Transfer trial, " & j)
 Next j
```

Comment: I've no idea what's going on in the "transfer" situation - I don't see any example data in the file you linked.  The code doesn't ignore "Practice" runs - it's just that you don't list those on the Summary sheet.

Comment: yer sorry I sent the original data file that doesn't have any transfer blocks. All my other files have them, and I'm just copy/pasting those data into the original file so I don't have to replicate all the code modules 35 times. [here's an example](http://www.filedropper.com/dotcountingpp1_1). The transfer blocks are listed in the summary sheet though. Also, it's interesting that the code to count AOIentries uses the same `if else` statement as the reaction times code, but doesn't have the same strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

quite difficult to follow what's going on in there

but you may try to change:

```
'count AOI entries
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If resBT(r, 1) = 1 Then  'only proceed with trials with 1 button press
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r
```

to:

```
'count AOI entries
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        If resBT(r, 1) = 1 And Left(resBT(r, 1), 8) <> "Transfer" Then  'only proceed with trials with 1 button press and not from a "Transfer" block
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)    'get count
        Else: dBT(k) = ""
        End If
    Next r
```

Comment: I actually want it to proceed with transfer blocks (just not the practice block at the start). But at the moment it is not proceeding with transfer blocks. No idea why. I found it difficult to follow as well. The dict is using COL_BLCOK and COL_TRIAL to create keys, but somehow it keys some values in COL_BLOCK but not others.

Comment: I can't remember and I don't have the sample file - if I'm going to take a look I'd rather see the whole thing.

Comment: @TimWilliams The sample file is in the link at the bottom of the question. [here it is again](http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest_2)